# Is there any way to deploy only one project in tomcat leaving the other projects

Tags: java, web-applications, tomcat7

I have multiple projects on my tomcat web-apps directory. When I start the tomcat then all the projects are deploying and it is taking time to deploy all the projects. Is there any way to deploy only one project and rest of the projects should not be deployed. I dont want to remove all files expect the file which needs to be deployed because all the files are connected to eclipse. Is there any way like commenting the projects so they will not deploy.

Comment: Why do you have to add files to web-apps?  IntelliJ does it without having to do so.

Comment: If you are starting tomcat from eclipse, right click on the server and use the add / remove button.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on eclipse:

- Export all your applications as .war and drop them on
  `<TOMCAT_DIR>/webapps`
- Start Tomcat with `<TOMCAT_DIR>/bin/startup` and let it deploy your applications.
- Remove the *.war* files of the applications you are not
  changing so the server will not redeploy all your applications.
- Use Eclipse to deploy the application you are working on, from the Tomcat `add and remove` option you should only add the application you are working on.

Comment: I’m not using any build tool to make it .war files. The project is just in right folder structure and I will start the tomcat to deploy.